Early 2000s Horror movie about a mother trying to find her child
When I was younger I was scrolling through the channels looking for something to watch. I came across a horror movie on the Syfy channel, I believe, and I can't remember what it's called. 
Plot: I believe the movie involved a mother trying to find out if her son or daughter is alive or not. It seems to me her husband didn't think they were and she was convinced they were out there. 
I remember the climax had the mother search through some strange house where reality seemed all bent and distorted and she ended up finding and saving her kid. But the twist of the movie was that when she brought her kid back to her house and to her husband, her husband only saw the kid. 
I remember vividly a door being closed in front of the mom, and she was shocked before realizing now she was the dead one or something like that. 
I believe the movie took place in some sort of lake house or house on the water, but I could be mixing that up with another movie I saw around the same time. 
I'm sure it was an early 2000s movie.

https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/16714/horror-film-where-couple-find-a-girl-who-is-unable-to-talk

Does it have Nicole Kidmann in it? If so, the film is called "the others"
